# Access data from main application within a plugin in C#

Tags: c#, plugins, system.reflection

I am using this approach to make my C#-application extensible for other developers:

[Creating a simple plugin mechanism](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62)

It works just fine but only in "one direction" which means that the developer who writes a new plugin can define methods and variables within the plugin and those will be imported to my application.

So my question is now: How can i access already existing data from my main application (e.g. a variable "string test") within the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an "SDK" for your application which is available to your plugin writers. This should contain interfaces for anything you want to make externally accessible.

e.g.

**MyAppSdk.dll**

```
public interface IMyApplicationContext {
    string SomeData { get; set; }
    IMyAppService SomeService { get; set; }
}

public interface IPlugin {
    void Do(IMyApplicationContext context)
}
```

**Plugin**

```
public class MyPlugin : IPlugin {
     public void Do(IMyApplicationContext context) { 
         context.SomeService.DoAThing();
         System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(context.SomeData);
     }
}
```

**Application**

```
context = GetApplicationContext();
plugin.Do(context);
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in detail the "Application" part? I do net get how i can access the information within my plugin. I already tried it with a get/set variable within the interface. Then i wanted to set information from my aplication at the loading-time of the plugin to it and get it within the plugin... But that did not work.

Comment: Assuming `IMyApplicationContext` is in an assembly shared by both your application and the plugin, you can implement it in your app and pass it to the plugin. How you do so is up to you, but I'd generally suggest DI.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.

You could create a `Dictionary<string, object>` where every module has access to set or get data. You should write some logic to access that dictionary. For example a `T GetData<T>(string key)` method to bring a bit type safety into it.

You could use an event system like `EventAggregator` in the PRISM framework to enable communication between your modules as well.

But be aware hat this will make your modules dependant from each other. That's why you should handle e.g. if data is not available from another module.

Comment: Where should i create the Dictionary? In my main application? But how can my plugin access it then?

Comment: You should create it in your main application and you could make it available in your modules when you create them: insert an instance of the class from which the dictionary is available (should be a singleton instance).

Comment: Should i add mainApplication to the references of the plugin? Otherwise the plugin do not know the classes from my main application and so i can't insert an instance of it.

Comment: I would not do this. Put the base classes in a dll and reference this dll in your main app and the modules. That's the better way