# C# - Use .exe as reference for plugin-projects to access objects from host application

Tags: c#, .net, plugins

I want to make my application extensible for other developers with plugins. For that I am using this approach:

[Creating a simple plugin mechanism](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b45f1d4e)

In my application I have several objects/classes which should be accessible and usable for the plugin-writers. I have great problems to achieve this function. I tried it already with interfaces which represent these classes which should be usable by plugin-writers ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45143326/8270129)). I also tried to separate these classes in a separated dll. But nothing worked because there are some dependencies between classes in my project (some open at initalisation new windows or need to access the current main window) and therefore they should stay all in my main project.

One way that would work is, that plugin-writers reference at their plugin-project the .exe of my application. Then they could use all objects of my application.

But I am not sure if this is 'bad coding' or something else and should better avoided?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] about what you have tried.

Comment: What dependency issues did you face when separating the interface in a second DLL?

Comment: One of the classes is a static class (and it must stay static). In this class dictionaries are created with objects from another class. I can't remember exactly the fault-message but it doesn't work when i used this class in the plugin because it was a static class.